# Angular Material mat-ripple isn't working

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to add ripple effect to one button, but it crashes whole webpage. 
When I just add `matRipple` to my button nothing happens. When I try to add color `[matRippleColor]="white"` I get **"Can't bind to 'matRippleColor' since it isn't a known property of 'button'"**.

That strange because I enabled ripples on other page of website and it works just fine. (So yes, I've imported MatRippleModule):[image]

HTML:

```
<button  matRipple class="submit-button" color="accent" type="submit" >
  <mat-icon>search</mat-icon><span>Szukaj</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

That is because the input property matRippleColor expect a string and you are passing a variable that Angular supposed you have initialized before and in this case you have a variable that I supposed doesn't exist in your component.

If you want the white color be recognized you have to pass it as string since you are using the binding feature:

```
[matRippleColor]="'white'"
```

or you can remove the curly brackets and using it like this:

```
matRippleColor="white"
```

Comment: Neither worked for me. Page still freezes when I try to set color for ripples. 
More of that, on my other page I used just matRipple [matRippleColor]="white" and it worked as it suppose to. (You see result on the screenshot in the topic).

Answer (score 1):

When you use `[matRippleColor]="white"`, Angular evaluates `"white"` to a template expression. Since you have not defined a variable `white` in your component, this evaluates to `undefined`. If you want to pass the color white to the `[matRippleColor]`, you need to pass it as a string like below

```
<button matRipple [matRippleColor]="'white'" type="submit" class="submit-button">
    <mat-icon>search</mat-icon><span>Szukaj</span>
</button>
```

The issue could also be with the version of `@angular/material` you are using. `MatRippleModule` works slightly differently for the different versions of `@angular/material`

`MatRippleModule` was introduced in Angular Material 6 so it will not work with versions 5 and below.

In Angular Material 6, the ripple overflows outside your element. This can be fixed by adding `position: relative` to your element CSS like below

```
.submit-button {
    position: relative;
}
```

In Angular Material 7, the `position: relative` CSS property has been added to the `.mat-ripple` class of the library so it is not required to add `position: relative` to the element in your CSS. The same goes for Angular Material 8.

Here is a simple example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ripple-color) on Angular 7 where you can dynamically change the color. For a constant color, just change `[matRippleColor]="rippleColor"` to `[matRippleColor]="'white'"` or any color of your choice.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. More of that, on my other page I used  just a 'white' and it worked! (result of that you see on the screenshot in the topic).

Comment: @Lbovsky I have edited my answer and added a working example on Stackblitz.